# Modify CKEditor link dialog to add custom attribute to links

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor on a website and I need to be able to put a special data attributes on some of the links created through the editor. The user would indicate that they need the special attribute put on the link by checking a checkbox in the link dialog. I have managed to add a checkbox to the link dialog with the following code:

```
CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function(ev) {
    if (ev.data.name == "link") {
        var info = dialog.getContents("info");
        info.elements.push({
            type: "vbox",
            id: "urlOptions",
            children: [{
                type: "hbox",
                children: [{
                    id: "button",
                    type: "checkbox",
                    label: "Button",
                    commit: function(data) {
                        data.button = this.getValue()
                        console.log("commit", data.button, data);
                    },
                    setup: function(data) {
                        this.setValue(data.button);
                        console.log("setup", data.button, data);
                    }
                }]
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

Now I have two problems. The first one is that despite me adding the code in the `commit` and `setup` functions that should save the state of the checkbox, it's not working. It's as if the `data` can't hold any other parameters but the ones there by default.

The second problem is that I don't know how to add / remove the data attribute on my links. It seems to me that I should be doing that in my `onOk` callback on the dialog, however, the link dialog already has an `onOk` callback, so I'm not sure how I should be proceeding. I, of course, do not want to modify any of CKEditor's files directly.

How can I accomplish these things?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You best option is to modify the plugin. So you need to open the source code and find the file `links.js` in `c:\ckeditor_3.6.5\ckeditor\_source\plugins\link\dialogs\`

The source code is quite big (40k) but here you can modify the dialog however you want. When you finish just copy it to your plugins folder, and compress it: http://jscompress.com/

I have done what you need myself. The whole uncompressed file is here: https://gist.github.com/3940239

What you need to do:

First add this line just before the dialog "browse" button is appended. Approx. in line: 547:

```
                        {
                            id: "button",
                            type: "checkbox",
                            label: "Button",
                            setup: function (data) {
                                this.allowOnChange = false;

                                if (data.button)
                                    this.setValue(data.button);

                                this.allowOnChange = true;
                            },
                            commit: function (data) {
                                data.button = this.getValue()
                                this.allowOnChange = false;
                            }
                        },
```

This part is actually your code. I just copied and pasted it.

Then, go to the onOk function, approx. in line 1211: and after commitContent add this code:

```
this.commitContent( data );

//My custom attribute
if (data.button)
    attributes["custom-attribute"] = "button";
else
    attributes["custom-attribute"] = "";
```

This will modify your link adding the attribute to the element such as `<a href="#" custom-attribute="button">text</a>`

That's it. Although, you may also like to load the current status of the checkbox. Then, go to the function `parseLink` . Approx. line 179 to load the attributes:

```
...
if ( element )
{
    retval.button = element.getAttribute('custom-attribute');

    var target = element.getAttribute( 'target' );
...
```

Comment: This is very good, but I'm worried about updating CKEditor and overwriting these changes after. Are you sure there are no ways around modifying the file itself?

Comment: I don't think there is another way to do this. I see your point, but you are only making 3 small changes to 1 file in the source code which should take 1 minute to re-do. 

You can always backup the "link" folder and treat it as a plugin. So if you need to update, you will always unzip that file that includes your own functionality.

Comment: @Xeon06 have you tried this? Reading the source code of CKEditor, the link dialog doesn't expose these functions to the main configuration. Modifying the source code is the only solution.

Comment: Oops sorry yes. Although its not what I wanted, it works. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is there not a way to modify the output of the link after the onOk function has completed?

Answer (score 0):

I am exploring the same thing now. What I have decided to do at this point is to:

1. Get a base ckeditor install without the link plugin
2. create my own fork of the link plugin, and add my changes to it, then activate and use this plugin within the group that link normally shows up in.

...working with it as a custom plugin (albeit a copy of the original) should alleviate the problem of upgrading. You just simply do not use the original link plugin at all. Copy and rename it, and use your custom copy instead.